# il2cpp android app unfortunately has stopped. unity

Tags: android, mono, il2cpp

When I build my game in mono works perfectly but when I switch to il2cpp it says when I want to start: app unfortunately has stopped. I have another android device and both the mono and il2cpp build work fine. So the app is good. I uploaded to google play and check the supported device list and I found my device in it so its should start.
My app api compatibility level is .Net standard 2.0 but I tried the .Net 4x but that did not work either.

In logcat I see the following error:

> 09.20 11:45:48.055 28578 28578 Error dalvikvm: JNI posting fatal error: Unable to load library: /data/app-lib/com.hesoyamgames.move-1/libunity.so [Cannot load library: ] 09. 20 11:45:48.075 28578 28578 Error dalvikvm: VM aborting 09. 20 11:45:48.075 28578 28578 Fatal libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00006fa2 (code=-6), thread 28578 (soyamgames.move)

What do you think, why can't I launch my game? My android device is not too old.

Comment: What is the error message? You can see it when you run Android Studio and look at the `logcat` tab

Comment: Here what i find:  Error dalvikvm: JNI posting fatal error: Unable to load library: /data/app-lib/com.hesoyamgames.move-1/libunity.so [Cannot load library: ]
@aalmigthy

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the complete error stack? @user11978667

Comment: coplete error stack? I use unity logcat and this is the all text. (I just copied the errors) @aalmigthy



09. 20 11:45:48.055 28578 28578 Error dalvikvm: JNI posting fatal error: Unable to load library: /data/app-lib/com.hesoyamgames.move-1/libunity.so [Cannot load library: ]
09. 20 11:45:48.075 28578 28578 Error dalvikvm: VM aborting
09. 20 11:45:48.075 28578 28578 Fatal libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00006fa2 (code=-6), thread 28578 (soyamgames.move)